# When merged with the Raven (using Soul of the Raven), is the Warlock immune to damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, unearthed-arcana

A Warlock with the Raven Queen patron can use the 6th level Soul of the Raven pact ability to merge with the Sentinel Raven, as written:

> As a Bonus action when your raven is perched on your shoulder, your body merges with your raven’s form. While merged, you become Tiny, you replace your speed with the raven’s, and you can use your action only to Dash, Disengage, Dodge, Help, Hide, or Search. During this time, you gain the benefits of your raven being perched on your shoulder.

Under the description of the Sentinel Raven, it says:

> While perched on your shoulder, the raven can’t be targeted by any attack or other harmful effect; only you can cast spells on it; it can’t take damage; and it is incapacitated.

Does this mean the Warlock cannot be targeted by attacks or harmful spells while merged with the Raven? In the same vein, if she CAN be targeted, would her AC be that of the Raven or her own? What about physical statistics?

Comment: Using your own logic: does it mean the warlock is incapacitated when merged? Obviously not.

Answer (score 32):

*Does this mean the Warlock cannot be targeted by attacks or harmful spells while merged with the Raven?*

You don't gain the benefits *the raven* gets when perched on your shoulder, but the benefits *you* gain when the raven is perched on your shoulder.

> While the raven is perched on your shoulder, 
>   you gain darkvision with a range of 30 feet and a 
>   bonus to your passive Wisdom (Perception) 
>   score and to Wisdom (Perception) checks. The 
>   bonus equals your Charisma modifier.

*In the same vein, if she CAN be targeted, would her AC be that of the Raven or her own? What about physical statistics?*

It doesn't specify anything besides your size/speed change and the limitation of what you can do with an action, so it seems that you retain all other stats.

Comment: From the mouth of the Raven Queen herself!

Comment: Unquestionably the correct answer.

Comment: I had to go and check the profile creation date just to be sure it wasn't created just for this answer. *it was not*

Comment: @ShadowKras can we consider this a *word of god* canonical answer?

Comment: @Mindwin I just waited for the right time to strike ;)

Comment: ...as any self-respecting Raven Royal would do.

Comment: Mindwin Rolls sanity check because contacted by  @TheRavenQueen  ....